# MongoDB: populating arrays on nested document with $lookup in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, nested, aggregate, grouping, lookup

I have these three collections and I'm trying to fully populate the `messages` field of the `messages_lists` collection by 'joining in' data from the other two collections.

**1. message_lists:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e96207ea4143b3204373534"), 
    "name" : "6bq32q8TcP", 
    "messages" : [
        {
            "inserted" : ISODate("2020-04-14T20:43:42.086+0000"), 
            "srcId" : "DNWLMSNW217480-20200414T194933Z"
        }, 
        {
            "inserted" : ISODate("2020-04-16T17:40:22.585+0000"), 
            "srcId" : "DNWLMSNW217737-20200416T163914Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

**2. messages:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e9615205bbcbe360ad40fb7"),
    "srcId" : "DNWLMSNW217480-20200414T194933Z", 
    "status" : "expired",  
    "versions" : [
        {
            "direction" : NumberInt(-1), 
            "points" : [ 50080.028, 50080.029 ]  
        }, 
        {
            "direction" : NumberInt(1), 
            "points" : [ 50080.028, 50080.029 ] 
        }
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e988b95ab20413033dbe9fb"), 
    "status" : "expired", 
    "srcId" : "DNWLMSNW217737-20200416T163914Z",  
    "versions" : [
        {
            "direction" : NumberInt(1), 
            "points" : [ 50060.096, 50060.097 ] 
        }, 
        {
            "direction" : NumberInt(-1), 
            "points" : [ 50060.096, 50060.097 ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**3. loc_points:**

```
{ 
    "locId" : 50060.096, 
    "road" : "A1", 
    "locCity" : NumberInt(445), 
    "locState" : NumberInt(260) 
},
{  
    "locId" : 50060.097, 
    "road" : "A1", 
    "locCity" : NumberInt(445), 
    "locState" : NumberInt(260) 
},
{ 
    "locId" : 50080.028, 
    "road" : "A2", 
    "locCity" : NumberInt(690), 
    "locState" : NumberInt(260)
},
{ 
    "locId" : 50080.029, 
    "road" : "A2", 
    "locCity" : NumberInt(690), 
    "locState" : NumberInt(260), 
}
```

My mongoDB version is 3.4.4 and this is my attempt to solve the problem:

**Step 1:**
I was able to successfully complete the first $lookup stage with this query:

```
db.getCollection("message_lists").aggregate([
    { $match: { name: '6bq32q8TcP' } },
    { $unwind: { path: '$messages', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'messages',
        localField: 'messages.srcId',
        foreignField: 'srcId',
        as: 'messages'
    }},
    { $unwind: { path: '$messages', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
    { $group: { 
        _id: null, 
        messages: { $push: '$messages' }
    }},
])
```

I'm fully satisfied with the result I'm getting back from the above query. It looks like this and basically managed to replace the reference `messages.srcId` to the `messages` collection in the original `messages_list` collection with the full message data contained in the `messages` collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "messages" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e9615205bbcbe360ad40fb7"), 
            "srcId" : "DNWLMSNW217480-20200414T194933Z",
            "status" : "expired", 
            "versions" : [
                {
                    "direction" : NumberInt(-1), 
                    "points" : [ 50080.028, 50080.029 ] 
                }, 
                {
                    "direction" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "points" : [ 50080.028, 50080.029 ] 
                }
            ] 
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e988b95ab20413033dbe9fb"), 
            "srcId" : "DNWLMSNW217737-20200416T163914Z",
            "status" : "expired", 
            "versions" : [
                {
                    "direction" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "points" : [ 50060.096, 50060.097 ]
                }, 
                {
                    "direction" : NumberInt(-1), 
                    "points" : [ 50060.096, 50060.097 ] 

                }
            ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

**Step 2:** The goal of this step is to populate the `messages.versions.points` arrays with data from the `loc_points` collection in order to get to the final result which is supposed to look like this:

**This is what I need the result to look like**:

```
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "messages" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e9615205bbcbe360ad40fb7"), 
            "srcId" : "DNWLMSNW217480-20200414T194933Z",
            "status" : "expired", 
            "versions" : [
                {
                    "direction" : NumberInt(-1), 
                    "points" : [ 
                      { 
                          "locId" : 50080.028, 
                          "road" : "A2", 
                          "locCity" : NumberInt(690), 
                          "locState" : NumberInt(260)
                      },
                      { 
                          "locId" : 50080.029, 
                          "road" : "A2", 
                          "locCity" : NumberInt(690), 
                          "locState" : NumberInt(260), 
                      }
                    ] 
                }, 
                {
                    "direction" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "points" : [ 
                      { 
                          "locId" : 50080.028, 
                          "road" : "A2", 
                          "locCity" : NumberInt(690), 
                          "locState" : NumberInt(260)
                      },
                      { 
                          "locId" : 50080.029, 
                          "road" : "A2", 
                          "locCity" : NumberInt(690), 
                          "locState" : NumberInt(260), 
                      }
                    ] 
                }
            ] 
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e988b95ab20413033dbe9fb"), 
            "srcId" : "DNWLMSNW217737-20200416T163914Z",
            "status" : "expired", 
            "versions" : [
                {
                    "direction" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "points" : [ 
                      { 
                          "locId" : 50060.096, 
                          "road" : "A1", 
                          "locCity" : NumberInt(445), 
                          "locState" : NumberInt(260) 
                      },
                      {  
                          "locId" : 50060.097, 
                          "road" : "A1", 
                          "locCity" : NumberInt(445), 
                          "locState" : NumberInt(260) 
                      }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "direction" : NumberInt(-1), 
                    "points" : [ 
                      { 
                          "locId" : 50060.096, 
                          "road" : "A1", 
                          "locCity" : NumberInt(445), 
                          "locState" : NumberInt(260) 
                      },
                      {  
                          "locId" : 50060.097, 
                          "road" : "A1", 
                          "locCity" : NumberInt(445), 
                          "locState" : NumberInt(260) 
                      }
                    ] 
                }
            ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

In order to get there my understanding is that I need to perform an additional $lookup like this:

```
{ $lookup: {
    from: 'loc_points',
    localField: 'messages.versions.points',
    foreignField: 'locId',
    as: 'messages.versions.points',
}},
{ $unwind: { path: '$messages.versions.points', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }}
```

However, after a full day of research and reading through at least five other stackoverflow threads I was unable to find a solution that is resembling my deeply nested document structure.

I would be really thankful if somebody who is more familiar with the mongoDB aggregation framework could help me out here! 
Thank you in advance!!

**Edit:**
After Joe's advise below I have added the second $lookup before the final $group statement. So now my overall query looks like this:

```
db.getCollection("message_lists").aggregate([
    { $match: { name: '6bq32q8TcP' } },
    { $unwind: { path: '$messages', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'messages',
        localField: 'messages.srcId',
        foreignField: 'srcId',
        as: 'messages'
    }},
    { $unwind: { path: '$messages', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'loc_points',
        localField: 'messages.versions.points',
        foreignField: 'locId',
        as: 'messages.versions.points',
    }},
    { $group: { 
        _id: null, 
        messages: { $push: '$messages' }
    }}
])
```

However, in the result `messages.versions.points` is returned as an empty array, all other `version` fields are missing and `messages.versions` isn't even an array anymore:

```
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "messages" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e9615205bbcbe360ad40fb7"), 
            "srcId" : "DNWLMSNW217480-20200414T194933Z",
            "status" : "expired", 
            "versions" : {
                "points" : [
                ]
            },  
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e988b95ab20413033dbe9fb"), 
            "srcId" : "DNWLMSNW217737-20200416T163914Z",
            "status" : "expired", 
            "versions" : {
                "points" : [
                ]
            },  
        }
    ]
}
```

I simply can't figure out how I need to modify the $group statement in order to populate `messages.versions.points` properly. Any help is appreciated! (I know, coming from the MySQL world I'm showing that I haven't fully grasped the concept of aggregation yet but at the same time I'm struggling to find a tutorial that fits my scenario)

Comment: When you lookup on `messages.versions.points`, it's returning single array for the entire document, not one fore each array element, so you'll need to unwind `version` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
db.message_lists.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$messages'
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'messages',
            localField: 'messages.srcId',
            foreignField: 'srcId',
            as: 'messages'
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            message: { $arrayElemAt: ["$messages", 0] },
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$message.versions'
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$message.versions.points'
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'loc_point',
            localField: 'message.versions.points',
            foreignField: 'locId',
            as: 'points'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$points'
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            message: {
                _id: '$message._id',
                srcId: '$message.srcId',
                status: '$message.status',
                versions: {
                    direction: "$message.versions.direction",
                    points: '$points'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { message_id: '$message._id', direction: '$message.versions.direction' },
            name: { $first: '$name' },
            srcId: { $first: '$message.srcId' },
            status: { $first: '$message.status' },
            points: {
                $push: '$message.versions.points'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            name: { $first: '$name' },
            srcId: { $first: 'srcId' },
            status: { $first: '$status' },
            versions: {
                $push: {
                    direction: '$_id.direction',
                    points: '$points'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: "$_id.message_id",
            name: 1,
            srcId: 1,
            status: 1,
            versions: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$versions'
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            status: { $first: '$status' },
            srcId: { $first: '$srcId' },
            versions: { $push: '$versions' }

        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            messages: { $push: '$$ROOT' }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: That works perfectly and solved my problem! Thanks a lot, Ghazanfar!

Answer (score 0):

The `$lookup` stage returns a single array for each source document in the pipeline.

If you used the additional `$lookup` stage you noted after the existing pipeline, it will add a single array that will contain the set of points referred to by any version of any of the messages.

In order to get the points populated for each version of each message, those will have to be unwound.  You already had the messages, so you'd need to unwind the versions and run the additional lookup, then group by message to collect the version back into an array, then the existing group to collect the messages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you explanation, Joe! However, I'm still struggling with implementing your advise. E.g. when I'm simply adding the 2nd $lookup mentioned above to the aggregate pipeline (and w/o adding another $group) I'm getting an empty result back that lookis like this: `{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "messages" : {
        "versions" : {
            "points" : [

            ]
        }
    }
}`  I'm getting totally lost there...

Comment: also please see my edits in the original question above. Thanks!